# How to enable iGPU for dual monitor use?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

So, I have an AMD RX 570 GPU with only one output (DVI). It was originally made for mining so that would answer why it only has 1 output. My CPU has an integrated GPU so I wanted to use that for dual monitor, however the PC just doesn't detect the iGPU. I checked in BIOS to see if there's any option regarding the iGPU, but I couldn't find anything.

How can I enable the iGPU?

Comment: Do you have anything connected to the iGPU? What make and model is your CPU? What make and model is your motherboard?

Comment: I had a DVI and VGA cables connected, I tried with both but no result. the CPU is quite old ( i5 2400) but it should have an iGPU. for the motherboard, i checked with msinfo32 it says DT71 on system model

Answer (score 0):

So, it is unfortunately no longer possible to find manuals for the Gateway DT71 PC you apparently have.

On my old ASRock Z68 board, I have to set the following BIOS setup options for enable the iGPU in addition to my primary PCIe graphics card:

- Advanced → North Bridge

  - Primary Graphics Adapter: PCI Express
  - iGPU Multi-Monitor: Enable

You may have similar options that are not yet enabled.

---

In case there are no options at all to enable the iGPU even when a PCIe graphics card is installed, you’re most likely out of luck. Depending on how much graphics performance you really need, simply getting a new graphics card with more outputs may actually be quite affordable.

If you have another PCIe 16x slot you could also install an *additional* PCIe graphics card. Low-end cards are quite cheap.

Comment: So, i did actually find an option in the Advanced tab called Onboard Graphics controller (which i think refers to the iGPU), However, the Onboard graphics controller is greyed out meaning i can't change it to Enabled/Disabled.

Comment: You could remove your dedicated graphics card to see if that makes these options available and your iGPU active.

Comment: I did try, it just sets itself to Enabled while still being greyed out.

Comment: I see. In that case your board may simply not support this. You’re probably better off getting a new graphics card with more outputs.

Comment: Alright, I think i'm just going to upgrade the graphics card as you said. Thank you for the time taken answering.